# Why does gcovr fail to create a report with g++ version 12?

Tags: c++, gcovr, g++12

I have recently upgraded my toolchain, which has caused `gcovr` to fail to produce any coverage output. Can anyone tell me if this is an issue with gcovr, or my toolchain, or missing dependencies?

Here is the example/comparison I used to verify:

example.cpp

```cpp
// Taken from gcovr user guide.
// example.cpp

int foo(int param)
{
    if (param)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    foo(0);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcovr` version:

```
gcovr 6.0

Copyright (c) 2013-2023 the gcovr authors
Copyright (c) 2013 Sandia Corporation.
Under the terms of Contract DE-AC04-94AL85000 with Sandia Corporation,
the U.S. Government retains certain rights in this software.
```

When using `g++` version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I get the proper result:

```
$ g++ -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -O0 example.cpp -o program
$ ./program
$ gcovr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           GCC Code Coverage Report
Directory: .
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
File                                       Lines    Exec  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
example.cpp                                    7       6    85%   7
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                          7       6    85%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However when using the updated version 12 toolchain:

```
g++-12 (Ubuntu 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I get the following result:

```
$ g++-12 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -O0 example.cpp -o program
$ ./program
$ gcovr
(ERROR) Trouble processing '/home/janjaap/workspace/testgcovr/program-example.gcda' with working directory '/home/janjaap/workspace/testgcovr'.
Stdout of gcov was >>None<< End of stdout
Stderr of gcov was >>None<< End of stderr
Current processed gcov file was None.
Use option --verbose to get extended informations.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 80, in worker
    work(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
    done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 536, in run_gcov_and_process_files
    out, err = gcov_cmd.run_with_args(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 515, in run_with_args
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: GCOV returncode was -11 (exited by signal).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 80, in worker
    work(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
    done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 536, in run_gcov_and_process_files
    out, err = gcov_cmd.run_with_args(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 515, in run_with_args
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: GCOV returncode was -11 (exited by signal).
(ERROR) Uncaught EXCEPTION
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/bin/gcovr", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/__main__.py", line 328, in main
    covdata = collect_coverage_from_gcov(options)
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/__main__.py", line 380, in collect_coverage_from_gcov
    with Workers(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 173, in __exit__
    self.wait()
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 164, in wait
    raise self.exceptions[0][1]
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/__main__.py", line 387, in collect_coverage_from_gcov
    contexts = pool.wait()
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 164, in wait
    raise self.exceptions[0][1]
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/workers.py", line 80, in worker
    work(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 323, in process_datafile
    done = run_gcov_and_process_files(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 536, in run_gcov_and_process_files
    out, err = gcov_cmd.run_with_args(
  File "/home/janjaap/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gcovr/gcov.py", line 515, in run_with_args
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: GCOV returncode was -11 (exited by signal).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run gcovr with a compiler other than your system's default `gcc`/`g++`, you must tell it which `gcov` tool to use. Since the binary coverage data format changes between compiler versions, the matching `gcov` must be used.

Here, you're using `g++-12`. The corresponding gcov is probably called `gcov-12`. You can tell gcovr to use this via the `--gcov-executable` option.

```bash
gcovr --gcov-executable gcov-12
```

Further reading: [*Choosing the Right Gcov Executable* in the gcovr documentation](https://gcovr.com/en/stable/guide/compiling.html#choosing-the-right-gcov-executable).